# How to show slide based on random slide number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#btnOner").click(function(){
    var min = 1;
    var max = 10;
    // and the formula is:
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            $(".part3 ul li img#"+random).animate({opacity: 1}, 3000);
            $(".part3 ul li img#"+random).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 3000);
        },3000);
    }
});
```

Hi, i have 10 pictures which have opacity, parameter is 0.5 .
I would like to create random number and which image has this number, its opacity will be 1. Then after 3 second again 0.5  and random another number and continue to 10 times. 

When i use like this some images show together, i want to 1 by 1

Excuse my bad english,

Thanks in advice

Comment: You might consider using setInterval() instead of setTimeout(). setInterval will continue to call after the specified time until you call clearInterval(). You will need to pass it the return value from the setInterval function

Comment: When you are doing your loop, you create the `setTimeout`s at the same time.  You should look into using promises. That way, you can wait until one is completed before starting the next.  http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$("#btnOner").click(function(){
    var min = 1;
    var max = 10;
    var i = min;

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        $(".part3 ul li img#"+random).animate({opacity: 1}, 3000);
        $(".part3 ul li img#"+random).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 3000);
        if (i > max)
            clearInterval(timer);
    },3000);
});
```

Comment: Close, but you want `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`.